# show 'ext ' when the ext field has value and not when it is empty

Tags: javascript, forms, vaadin

I have a query for including ext number after phone  number. When the ext is empty the string 'ext' still should shows when submitted. The idea is to show ext when there is value.

This is the HTML

```
<vaadin-grid-column>
    <template>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.contactPhones}}">
        {{item.phoneType.name}}:
             <div>[[item.phoneNumber]] {{_showExt(item.phoneExtension)}}</div>
        </template>
        </template>
    </vaadin-grid-column>
```

Here is the logic:

```
_showExt(val) {
   if (val != undefined) {
      return 'ext ' + val;
   }
      return ''
```

Comment: What is the value of item.phoneExtension. Is it an empty string? Are you sure it is undefined? If it's an empty string then '' != undefined will return true.

Comment: You are right, The value should be either ' ' or null for it to work.